# Text floating to right is almost outside of li

Tags: html, css

Continuing the question through the title...

My html `li` has a padding, but when I remove it, the text is positioned as before yet, almost outside of its own container. And I'm just testing, though.
[Some view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9Snb.png) (I'm not allowed to add images yet)... I just want that the text be inside its container.

The respective content is:

(***note***: the class `no-s` just removes the ugly selection)

```css
/* Context menu */

.context-menu {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 4px 0 4px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #628;
}

.context-menu list {
  list-style: none
}

.context-menu li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 100px
}

.context-menu .base,
.context-menu .second {
  display: inline-block
}

.context-menu .base {
  float: left
}

.context-menu .second {
  float: right
}

.context-menu li .active,
.context-menu li .inactive {
  display: inline-block;
  font: 600 14px"Segoe Ui", sans-serif
}
```

```html
<div class="context-menu no-s" style="left: 60px; top: 60px;">
  <list>
    <!-- A context menu item -->
    <li>
      <!--Left content-->
      <div class="base">
        <span class="active">Copy</span>
      </div>

      <!--Right content-->
      <div class="second">
        <span class="active">CTRL + C</span>
      </div>

    </li>
  </list>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to change the padding of the `.context-menu`?

I changed it to this: `padding: 4px 20px 4px 0;` and it seems to work

```css
/* Context menu */

.context-menu {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 4px 20px 4px 0; /* changed right padding */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #628;
  
}

.context-menu list {
  list-style: none;    
}

.context-menu li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 100px
}

.context-menu .base,
.context-menu .second {
  display: inline-block
}

.context-menu .base {
  float: left;    
}

.context-menu .second {
  float: right;  
}

.context-menu li .active,
.context-menu li .inactive {
  /* display: inline-block;  */
  font: 600 14px"Segoe Ui", sans-serif
}
```

```html
<div class="context-menu no-s" style="left: 60px; top: 60px;">
  <list>
    <!-- A context menu item -->
    <li>
      <!--Left content-->
      <div class="base">
        <span class="active">Copy</span>
      </div>

      <!--Right content-->
      <div class="second">
        <span class="active">CTRL + C</span>
      </div>

    </li>
  </list>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, that makes sense... I found another solution, though. I find this more pratice, though. The problem was exactly the padding :/ With that solution the text will get some extra space.

Answer (score 2):

you can delete the padding-left (even if necessary padding-right but now not necessary) from here;

```
.context-menu li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 100px
}
```

that's all

or you can use flexbox model for this section.

Comment: It's making the text float outside... then remove it is right. It was possible to add the property to `.base` now, also... so `flexbox` wouldn't be necessary